# Custom draw ListView Items without border per how TListView itself does it

Tags: winapi, c++builder, vcl

In a custom control, I custom-draw `TListView` items myself in the `TListView.OnAdvancedCustomDrawItem` event.  This works well.

I have been experimenting with several Theme classes and parts. For instance, when I use:

```
HTHEME Theme = OpenThemeData(Handle, L"Explorer::ListView") ;
DrawThemeBackground (Theme, Sender->Canvas->Handle, LVP_LISTITEM, LISS_NORMAL, &ItemRect, NULL);
```

I get what is to be expected, per Theme explorer (do notice the borders around the item):

[image]

But, if I look at a proper VCL `TListView` object, similar items are painted **without** a border.  I expected this control to use the same Theme class and part.  Is that not the case?  If so, what class/part should I use to mimic the behavior?

This is what I see (notice the borders in the custom control vs the absence of borders in the true TListView control just below it:

[image]

I'm actually getting a 'nicer' result with `LVP_GROUPHEADER`, but I'm still very curious about `LVP_LISTITEM`.

FYI, using `LVP_GROUPHEADER` instead of `LVP_LISTITEM`.  It works well for this type control, so a nice alternative, but I'm still very curious as to why the real ListView control paints no borders using `LVP_LISTITEM` (I THINK).

[image]

Perhaps I should add that I still use old C++ Builder 2009 for this project.  This is a low effort attempt to improve the control to give it a life beyond W10 (Especially W11 where current MENU / MENU_POPUPITEM choice is not kind on the eyes).  PS. having more problems with TPopupMenu now .. but that's another topic I guess.

A simple code example (not same as in project but showing the border):

```
#include "uxtheme.h"
#include "Vsstyle.h"

// Project includes uxtheme.lib

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
HTHEME Theme = OpenThemeData(Handle, L"Explorer::ListView") ;

TRect ItemRect = Image1->ClientRect ;

DrawThemeBackground (Theme, Image1->Canvas->Handle, LVP_LISTITEM, LISS_NORMAL, (tagRECT*)&ItemRect, NULL);

CloseThemeData(Theme) ;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you tried the other ListView theme? It seems [*You can mix and match control parts by calling OpenThemeData multiple times for a given control and using the appropriate theme handle to draw different parts*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/using-visual-styles#drawing-controls-with-visual-styles).

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you are seeing when things don't paint the borders the way you are expecting?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Done, though I'm not sure why since the border is to be expected using this theme.

Comment: On a side note: you are leaking the `HTHEME` handle since you are not calling `CloseThemeData()`. Also, `&(Image1->ClientRect)` is technically illegal, since `ClientRect` returns a temporary `TRect` and you are not allowed to take the address of a temporary.

Comment: Fair points.  It was a quick and dirty.